# Array pasted incorrectly using appendRow

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is the code:

```
    function worksheet(){
var arraymi = worksheetmi.getRange("A2:D").getValues();
var arraymi_n = [];
var arrayme = worksheetme.getRange("A2:D").getValues();
var arrayme_n = [];

for(x in arraymi){

if(arraymi[x][1] || arraymi[x][2] != ""){
var last = arraymi[x].pop();
arraymi[x].unshift(last);
arraymi_n.push(arraymi[x])
}}

for(x in arrayme){

if(arrayme[x][1] || arrayme[x][2] != ""){
var last = arrayme[x].pop();
arrayme[x].unshift(last);
arrayme_n.push(arrayme[x])

}}
var bdarray = bdworksheet.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
var length = bdarray.filter(String).length;
var bdarray = bdworksheet.getRange("A1:D"+length+"").getValues();
for(x in arraymi_n){
bdarray.push(arraymi_n[x]);
}
for(x in arrayme_n){
bdarray.push(arrayme_n);
}


var length = bdarray.length;
bdworksheet.getRange(1,1,bdarray.length,bdarray[1].length).setValues(bdarray);
}
```

This is the error:

> Incorrect range width, was 253 but should be 4 (line 132, file "Code")

Any ideas why is this happening? I've done that before using the same method but that 253 width is bugging me!

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you are passing a double array as an argument of [`appendRow`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendrowrowcontents), which expects a single array of row contents, like `['q', 'w', 'e', 'r']`.

To insert a double array, use getRange... setValues combination, as follows:

```
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var values = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]];
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
```

This automatically adds rows as needed.

Comment: Does bdarray have consistent row length? Try `Logger.log(bdarray.map(function(r) {return r.length}))` for debugging